# what is angular js compiler linking function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile, custom-directive

I am a bit confused about the line taken from Angular JS official documentation:

Compile: traverse the DOM and collect all of the directives. The result is a **linking function**.

I am not clear about what linking functions are?

Are they talking about link function that we write in a custom directive?

Please clarify using an example.

Comment: Maybe.  Can you provide a link to the specific part of the documentation you are referring to?

Comment: here is the link for official Angular JS documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler

Comment: See [THIS Example on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/ij4o5VDS45I9OF8El6zj?p=preview)